# Change SRC of IFrame inside IFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, clone, src

In this case I have a apDiv containing an IFrame that I am cloning with JQuery. This IFrame's SRC also contains an IFrame that I'm trying to change the SRC of.

My current thinking has this code; but I can't see why it doesn't work.

```
  $('#image').live('click',
                    function(){ 

$('#apdiv').clone().css({'left': 478,'top': 275, 'z-index': 0,})
.appendTo('body').find("iframe")
.contents().find('#iFrame_content2').attr({ src: "http://www.newsrc.co.uk" });
});
```

Incidentally, I can change the SRC of the first IFrame if before ".contents()" I put the ".attr()" code.

But I cannot seem to reach the second IFrame in the same way.

I'm clearly missing something, if you can help!

PS all IFrame's SRC are on the same domain as index, so cross domain stuff should not apply.

Answer (score 0):

check out this link http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
 $('#image').live('click',
                    function(){ 

$('#apdiv').clone().css({'left': 478,'top': 275, 'z-index': 0,})
.appendTo('body').find("iframe")
.contents().find('#iFrame_content2').attr("src","http://www.newsrc.co.uk");
});
```

You are trying to attr like css.

Comment: Yeah, I tried writing the attr like that, but it still has no effect. Yet when written in both ways, it works to change the SRC of the first IFrame if I apply it to that.  Why will it not change the second IFrame?